minor compiling error in c++ in function return
QUESTION:
Given an array of integers nums and an integer target, return indices of the two numbers such that they add up to target.
You may assume that each input would have exactly one solution, and you may not use the same element twice.
You can return the answer in any order.
Example 1:
Input: nums = [2,7,11,15], target = 9
Output: [0,1]
Explanation: Because nums[0] + nums[1] == 9, we return [0, 1].

if needed more you can visit the questions = (https://leetcode.com/problems/two-sum/description/)
I have solved this question with brute force solution however i am facing issues in c++ concept or maybe some basic interpretting issue.
My code:
class Solution {
public:
    vector<int> twoSum(vector<int>& nums, int target) {
        int n = nums.size();
        vector<int> ans;
        for ( int i = 0; i < n; i++){
            for ( int j = i+1; j < n ; j++){
                if ( nums[i] + nums[j] == target){
                    ans.push_back(i);
                    ans.push_back(j);
                    return ans;
                }
            }
        }
        
    }
};

However this solution is not showing compiling error =
Line 16: Char 5: error: non-void function does not return a value in all control paths [-Werror,-Wreturn-type]
   16 |     }
      |     ^
1 error generated.

So I prepared another solution which is working but i cant figure out the reason why the previous code is not working and this is.
class Solution {
public:
    vector<int> twoSum(vector<int>& nums, int target) {
        int n = nums.size();
        vector<int> ans;
        for ( int i = 0; i < n; i++){
            for ( int j = i+1; j < n ; j++){
                if ( nums[i] + nums[j] == target){
                    ans.push_back(i);
                    ans.push_back(j);
                }
            }
        }
        return ans;
    }
};

Somebody please explain the logic.
edit: i have done the dry run and for every input it is necessary that if ( nums[i] + nums[j] == target)  will be executed and a return value will be given

Please clarify how your issue deals with Digital Signature A (dsa tag).  I'm having trouble seeing the relationship.

Put yourself in the compilers shoes.  In the first example, what happens if the outer loop ends without the if condition inside ever being satisfied?

With the return in the first code there is no guarantee that return will ever be called.

What happens if nums[i] + nums[j] == target is never true?

i have done the dry run and for every input it is necessary that if ( nums[i] + nums[j] == target) will be executed and a return value will be given The compiler does not know that. And it will warn about a potential problem.

To solve your problem, you need to have two return statements: One that is returned if the condition is true, and one that returns an empty vector if the condition is never true and all the loops just ends.

nums[i] + nums[j] == target will always be true as i specified that according to my input  it should always return a value

@picki_panda And can you always guarantee the input to lead to such a result?

What does the function return if nums is an empty vector.

The problem is that the condition "You may assume that each input would have exactly one solution" specified in the task is not known to the compiler. This an external piece of information, not following from the code itself.

@drescherjm well i specified that my input will always be such that if condition will be called.

Are you still asking about Char 5: error: non-void function does not return a value in all control paths ?

Also (although not related to the problem), the variables n, i and j should be of type std::size_t (not int), because this is what std::vector::size() returns.

Just for kicks, the more efficient solution is quite straightforward. Sort the array, and place a pointer on the first last elements. Until you have your sum or the pointers cross paths, take the sum and adjust one of the pointers accordingly. You now have an O(nlgn) solution as opposed O(n^2).

It is possible for nums[i] + nums[j] == target to never be evaluated as true, the compiler cannot know what the question said, meaning that the function would complete execution without returning.  The second code block compiles because there is no possible path for the function to complete without returning.
The "proper" way would probably be to either use a container with a fixed size or declare the vector with a size of 2, initialize it to some known "error" value, and add a break; after you asign the correct values.
